# Does drush need to be installed as root?

Tags: installation

Per http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

```
# Download latest stable release using the code below or browse to github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases.
php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush
# Or use our upcoming release: php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush-unstable.phar');" > drush

# Test your install.
php drush core-status

# Make `drush` executable as a command from anywhere. Destination can be anywhere on $PATH.
chmod +x drush
sudo mv drush /usr/local/bin

# Optional. Enrich the bash startup file with completion and aliases.
drush init
```

So I try it but get the following error:

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush
[Michael@devserver ~]$ php drush core-status
PHP Warning:  pcntl_exec(): Error has occurred: (errno 13) Permission denied in phar:///home/Michael/drush/includes/startup.inc on line 359

Warning: pcntl_exec(): Error has occurred: (errno 13) Permission denied in phar:///home/Michael/drush/includes/startup.inc on line 359
Error has occurred executing the Drush script found at /home/Michael/drush
(errno 13) Permission denied
[Michael@devserver ~]
```

So then I try running it as root.

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ su -
Password:
[root@devserver ~]# php /home/Michael/drush core-status
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /home/Michael/drush
 Drush version          :  8.1.2
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :

[root@devserver ~]#
```

So, all is good, and I just need to install it as root?  Any way I can install it as a normal user?  Thanks

Comment: The cause could be the location where drush was downloaded requires `sudo`. Similar to `sudo mv drush /usr/local/bin`, /usr/local/bin requires `sudo` to mv something into it.

Comment: To  Pierre.Vriens, No Sssweat, Clive,  different question.  I am asking whether I need to install as root, not run as root.

Comment: yes !! u need 2 install it as root or sudoer as its files get installed in the bin directory as said above and that's d normal way since r,w,x, privileges are only with d sudoer but if the user has been granted permissions he can run drush ..as ur last query says  [Any way I can run it as a normal user?]  refer to this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/20497/60708 .. to sum it up u need 2 install it as root but can run as root or user(if d user has the required privileges)@user1032531..i am bound 2 answer this becoz i was d one  who referred 2 them as an duplicate...Do rectify me @Thanks

Comment: @make-me-alive  You are rectified!  I think I got it now.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: vlcme :) @user1032531

Comment: @user1032531 Ah ok, I think that's covered - just to dispel the myths in the comments so far, the answer is no, you categorically do not have to install drush using root. You could, but most people don't

Comment: @Clive  Then why am I getting the error that I posted in the original question?  Note I would rather not install as root, and more importantly want to better understand what is going on.  Thanks

Comment: Not at the computer at the mo so can't check properly, but at a guess...if pcntl_exec is getting permission denied it might be because the file isn't executable. Try `chmod +x drush`

Comment: @Clive Doesn't the question in the last line.. contradict the title ??
the last line should be :
Can I only install it as root ? or is there a way to install it as a normal user ?

Comment: @Clive  `drush` is a PHP file, no?  Is being executable relevant?

Comment: @make-me-alive  Sorry, that was a typo in my original post.  It has since been updated.

Comment: I haven't thought it through very much to be honest. But permission denied on an exec command can often mean the process doesn't have execute permissions over the target

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure exactly what's going on there but I can reproduce it using the installation instructions.

The problem is related to the execution path (haven't looked any deeper). If you move out of the folder you downloaded drush into and execute, it'll work. (`cd ~/..; Michael/drush core-status`).

That's probably why it works when you `su` - your working directoy changes to /root. An unfortunate red herring, the problem doesn't appear to be related to permissions at all. Had you run `sudo php drush core-status`, it still wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Your exact code didn't work for me, but `[Michael@devserver home]$ php ~/drush core-status` did.  Odd, but at least I can go forward as a regular user!  Thanks.  PS.  If you or anyone figures out why, please comment.

Comment: Oddly enough, executing the commands outside of the dir as you suggested worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed!
`cd ~`
`php ~/drush core-status`

worked for me as well :)

Comment: That should be related to file permission make sure drush is executable!

Comment: It's not @Mehdi, it's a bug in drush. See Christopher's answer for more details

Comment: @Clive Do you have an idea what is the output of `php /tmp/drush core-status` ?

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly here is the output https://gist.github.com/geraldvillorente/6f31f3b24933b46309ad3f2cfb75c573

Answer (score 15):

**NOTE** The issue described in the Question has now be fixed in the latest Drush version.

No, Drush does not need to be installed as root.

I've submitted [Drush pull #2246](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/2246) to update the current Drush install instructions.

This install method fixes the issue as per [Drush pull #2246](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/2246):

```
# Download latest stable release using the code below or browse to github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases.
php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > /tmp/drush
# Or use our upcoming release: php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush-unstable.phar');" > /tmp/drush

# Test your install.
php /tmp/drush core-status

# Make `drush` executable as a command from anywhere. Destination can be anywhere on $PATH.
chmod +x /tmp/drush
sudo mv /tmp/drush /usr/local/bin

# Optional. Enrich the bash startup file with completion and aliases.
drush init
```

Comment: See https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/2246#issuecomment-237177485 for an explanation.

Comment: should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error as well. For my case it did turn out to be a permission issue on the given account. I needed to make sure the **~/.drush** directory (and its sub directories) where owned by the proper account:

```
chown -R <account_name>:<account_group> /home/<account_name>/.drush
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the order of the commands so that you make drush executable before you test the install, it works. (At least it did for me):

```
# Download latest stable release using the code below or browse to github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases.
php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush
# Or use our upcoming release: php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush-unstable.phar');" > drush

# Make `drush` executable as a command from anywhere. Destination can be anywhere on $PATH.
chmod +x drush
sudo mv drush /usr/local/bin

# Test your install.
php drush core-status

# Optional. Enrich the bash startup file with completion and aliases.
drush init
```

Comment: Worked for me, with the following change:  
`php /usr/local/bin/drush core-status`